# Assign dynamically loaded html element to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to validate fields loaded using jQuery `$().load();`.

with jquery validation plugin (jqueryvalidation.org)

My code is:

```
  var contactForm = $('#contact-form');
       contactForm.validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: false,
                phoneUS: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            }
        }
      });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with elements loaded with load();

After some google searching I found some solution but they all are aimed on "events", not to pass dynamically added input to variable:

```
 $(document).on('click','#submit',function() {});
```

I also tried to approach it with this code bellow :

```
$('.home').click(function() {
    $("#article").load("./ #article  > *",function(){
      contactForm = $(this).find("#contact-form");
    });
```

Also doesn't work though :(

I will appreciate any clues and help.

Comment: Just a side note: Never use `click` events for forms as keyboard submission can bypass it (browser dependant). Use the `submit` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add them dynamically :

```
$("#contact-form").find('input').each(function () { 
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, I don't want to make each input required, I want to find form and apply function .validate() that consist certain rules.

Comment: Please add the html to your OP and specify the fields added dynamically,